Azure Devops pipelines -- is it possible to make it so stages are opt-in instead of opt out?
So my team uses azure devops pipeline stages to deploy to different environments. Most of these stages are tied to our release promotion environments (ex: we have an integration environment, rc environment, prod staging environment, then finally prod), and it's built such that you have to pass each previous stage to promote to the next (along with a whole bunch of managerial and itops approvers). There's no risk of accidentally promoting past our dev environments in day-to-day work.
That said we do have three upstream environments that are shared among about 10 contributor level team members and do not have any approval process; sometimes someone will just select their branch and fire away, initiating an execution on all stages/environments. This leads to about an hour of havoc because suddenly upstream environments no longer have code to support expected features and QA writes all sorts of invalid bugs. Also, if the approvers in management and ITOPs are paying attention to their emails they'll see messages about approving stages for the promotion-to-prod cycle which brings up embarrassing "process" questions.
Is it possible to make it so stages are opt-in vs opt-out, so a dev has to pick the specific environment he wants to deploy to? I know the alternative is just having approval gates on all environments, but that would lead to situations where folks just (implicitly) select everything and approve only what they want, leading to a large number of bunk approval emails.
TL;DR; when I click "stages" when running a pipeline, I want to see all checkboxes unchecked by default, if I don't click "stages" and just fire away I want the pipeline to do nothing.

Hi @Sidney, the stages are checked by default in yaml pipeline. Checked on my side, the workaround is to use the parameter to validate the states and skip the unnecessary stages. Details added below, thanks.


when I click "stages" when running a pipeline, I want to see all checkboxes unchecked by default, if I don't click "stages" and just fire away I want the pipeline to do nothing.

In yaml pipeline, the stages are checked by default. As a workaround, you can use parameter to store the stages to run, so the dev will have to type the stage name to run. Code sample below:
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: stages
  type: string

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  stageList: ${{parameters.stages}}

stages:
- stage: dev
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'dev')
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"

- stage: staging
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'staging')
  jobs:
  - job: B
    steps:
    - bash: echo "B"

- stage: prod
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'prod')
  jobs:
  - job: C
    steps:
    - bash: echo "C"

When try to run the pipeline, have to type the parameter value which contains the target stages' name to start. Other stages will be skipped.


In Classic release pipeline, the mostly nearby way is to set the first stage as manual. Sample as below:

When you create the new release run, it has no stages to run. Have to choose the target stage to deploy. You can also set other stages as manual or add approval if needed.



when I click "stages" when running a pipeline, I want to see all checkboxes unchecked by default

I don't think that's possible.

if I don't click "stages" and just fire away I want the pipeline to do nothing

What exactly does it mean "do nothing"? Please note that the pipeline must have at least one stage and/or one job, otherwise it will fail when you try to queue a new build.
Controlling which stages to run by default
You can use boolean parameters to control which stages will run or not.
Something like:

In the pipeline code you can use conditions to generate the stage based on the value of the boolean parameter:
name: test-pipeline-1

parameters:
  - name: runOnProductionMode
    displayName: 'Run on production mode'
    type: boolean
    default: true

trigger: none

pool: Default

stages:
  - ${{ if parameters.runOnProductionMode }}:
    - stage: Build
      jobs:
        - job: Build
          steps:
            - script: echo "Building the application"

    - stage: Test
      jobs:
        - job: Test
          steps:
            - script: echo "Testing the application"

    - stage: Deploy
      jobs:
        - job: Deploy
          steps:
            - script: echo "Deploying the application"
  
  - ${{ if not(parameters.runOnProductionMode) }}:
    - stage: Foo
      jobs:
        - job: foo
          steps:
            - script: echo "Foo"

    - stage: Bar
      jobs:
        - job: bar
          steps:
            - script: echo "Bar"

